# Python SVG find paths that are adjacent, neighboring or intersect?

Tags: python, svg

A seemingly easy task has me bumping my head for hours...
The question I have is, is there a way to use python to find all adjacent, neighboring or intersecting paths? Using ["svgpathtools"](https://pypi.org/project/svgpathtools/) I have not managed to get an answer.
Using this code:

```
p1 = Path("M159,511L154,511L150,514L147,515L145,519L149,523L149,523L150,523L150,523L153,523L156,526L157,527L159,527L159,526L160,524L163,522L163,518L163,516L162,517L159,512L160,512L159,511Z")
p2 = Path("M176,511L174,509L171,510L168,510L162,506L161,506L161,506L162,509L161,510L160,512L159,512L162,517L163,516L163,518L163,522L160,524L159,526L159,527L160,527L165,527L168,525L171,521L172,521L171,519L170,516L173,515L178,511L177,511L176,511Z")

intersections = []
for (T1, seg1, t1), (T2, seg2, t2) in p1.intersect(p2):
    intersections.append(p1.point(T1))
print(intersections)
```

I only get "AssertionError". Any other way to get this done in python would be appreciated as well!

My guess is that the function will not work because there is no intersection but the paths generated are next to each other, so which function will return "True" if these paths are next to each other/are neighbors?

Answer (score 0):

I've played with your data with a simple JS (see the snippet below).
All you need is to parse the `path` strings and count the common points in both paths (you have 9). If you have at least 2 common point with sequential indices, you paths are neighboring.

```js
const getPathPoints = pathId => {
    const path = d3.select(`#${pathId}`).attr('d');
  
  const p = path.split(/[\s,MLZ]+/).slice(1, -1).reduce((all, coord, index) => {
  if (index % 2 === 0) 
    all.push({x: coord});
  else 
    all[all.length - 1].y = coord;
  return all;
  }, [])
  return p;
};

const first = getPathPoints('path1');
const second = getPathPoints('path2');
const common = first.reduce((all, point, index) => {
  const samePointIndex = second.findIndex(sp => sp.x === point.x && sp.y === point.y);
  if (samePointIndex >= 0)
    return {...all, [index]: samePointIndex};
  return all;  
}, {});

console.log('Common points: ', Object.keys(common).length);
```

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

path {
  fill: none;
  stroke-opacity: 0.5;
}

#path1 {
  stroke: blue;
}

#path2 {
  stroke: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="200" height="150">
  <g transform="scale(5) translate(-140,-500)"> 
  <path id="path1" d="M159,511L154,511L150,514L147,515L145,519L149,523L149,523L150,523L150,523L153,523L156,526L157,527L159,527L159,526L160,524L163,522L163,518L163,516L162,517L159,512L160,512L159,511Z"/>
  <path id="path2" d=M176,511L174,509L171,510L168,510L162,506L161,506L161,506L162,509L161,510L160,512L159,512L162,517L163,516L163,518L163,522L160,524L159,526L159,527L160,527L165,527L168,525L171,521L172,521L171,519L170,516L173,515L178,511L177,511L176,511Z" />
  </g>
</svg>
```